# Suggestion of Material design framework

Tags: user-interface, material-design

We are maintaining a web based tool (written in Play 2.x Framework) which over the years has gained a lot of different technologies used. It is a mix between regular server generated pages with old school html/javascript/html buta also som jQuery and misc components that the developer at that time liked. The more lately added stuff are more interactive and uses a REST-API and React.

Usability is pretty good but the graphical design of it is awful. In the best of worlds we would redo the entire front and make it single page and extend the REST-API fully. 
however, we don't have those resources but still apply a material design to it with a dark theme.

I have previously done a makeover on a similar but smaller web tool using Material Design Lite and that was quite smooth. However, that framework from what I can see does not support a dark theme and is also discontinued in favour for the Material Components.

Any suggestion on a good alternative?

Main requirements:

1. Uses a dark theme
2. Easy to integrate with both our old and newer stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you're use **React** you can try [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/).

If not you can simply make custom theme using [Material Design](https://material.io/design/introduction/).